# Golang , почему не выполняется функция?

Tags: golang

Почему у меня не выполняется функция foo()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Ok")
}

func foo() {
    fmt.Println("ff")
    foo()
}
```

Только основная main() функция, я вроде бы иницилизировал её.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы foo выполнилась ее надо вызвать из main.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

func main() {
    foo();
    fmt.Println("Ok")
}

func foo() {
    fmt.Println("ff")
    foo()
}
```

но так лучше не делать у вас там еще и рекурсия. foo вызывает саму себя.

И чтобы не было рекурсии, требуется убрать из функции foo вызов самой себя

```
func foo() {
    fmt.Println("ff")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А чтоб рекурсия не создавалась?

Comment: А, ну это понятно, я просто думал у меня в main функции рекурсия идет.